# ios launch animation with sprite kit

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, skspritenode

**How can I implement a starting/launching animation of a app in the best way possible? of course mainly in terms of performance?**

Starting with sprite kit I occured the problem of deciding the best way to implement a starting/launching animation (like in skype or twitter or other apps that have a animation before the app becomes active)  for my game.

I tried to make the animation using a node, but somehow it doesn't feel right. The animation is not yet part of the game.

```
SKSpriteNode* startScreen;
[startScreen runAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:startImages timePerFrame:kDigitTimePerStartAnimation] completion:^{
    [self animationStopped];
}];
```

Doing it in the first game controller as a UIImageView with some images to be played also seems not right because Sprite Kit is the one optimised for working with graphics.

```
[imageView startAnimating];
```

(I know it's not a big deal for the iOS to run some images in sequence, but I'm a little bit idealistic).

Waiting for proposals.

Comment: What do you mean by "starting animation"? What's your current implementation? Since you asked for "the best way" it implies you already know one or more solutions. Still, it's better to ask for "better ways" because there's hardly ever an undisputable "best way" to do something.

Comment: Tried to be more explicit. Hope it helps.

Comment: "doesn't feel right" isn't exactly the definition of "explicit" ;)
You are correct assuming that you should prefer to do the animation with Sprite Kit, but I'm lost as to why you consider that not an option or somehow not a good solution. I mean typically one presents the first scene that does the launch (loading) animation, and when the anim (or the loading of resources) is complete, one presents another scene which would probably show the game's main menu.

Comment: Then, more specifically.. I am using a SKNode, which theoretically should represent a hero, or enemy, or other object on a scene that somehow interact. My animation is none of them, but still it is run through an SKNode object. Is it possible to use a SKScene "native" property for the animation? Or it can only be done through a node inside that scene?